# Redirecionar para outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Colegas.

Como eu faria para que o usuário ao fechar o browser ou aba, fosse direcionado para outra página, porém que não funcionasse quando desse o F5. Digo isso pq tenho um sistema do qual tem o status online e offline e muitos deles estão fechando pelo navegador ou aba e o status continua online. A ideia e quando fechar o browser ou aba, ser direcionado para uma página onde eu pudesse desligar ele do sistema e dali fechar o navegador.

Procurando daqui e dali, achei esse código,  porém nao está funcionando, mas pode ser um ponto de partida... vejam:

```
<script>
var check;
function fechasess(url,e) {

if (url == 'f5') { //Entra quando uma tecla é apertada

if (e.keyCode == 116) { check = 1; } //Verifica se a tecla é F5 no IE, se for bloqueia o logout

if (e.which == 116) { check = 1; } //Verifica se a tecla é F5 no FF, se for bloqueia o logout

}else if (url == 'logout.php') { //Entra quando o onunload ativa

if (check != 1) { document.location=(url); } //Verifica se deve ativar o logout ou não
}else{ //Entra quando for um link
check = 1; //Bloqueia o logout 

document.location=(url); //Redireciona o link
}
}
</script>
<body onkeydown="fechasess('f5',event)" onkeypress="fechasess('f5',event)" onbeforeunload="fechasess('logout.php')" onunload="fechasess('logout.php')">
```

Comment: Parece que você quer algo impossível, mas não sei se entendi direito. Você só pode interceptar a saída da página pelos eventos `unload` e `beforeunload`, e eles rodam tanto ao fechar a aba ou janela, quanto ao recarregar a página. Mas não entendi bem a ideia de redirecionar quando a pessoa tenta fechar o browser. Se ele será fechado, nem adiantaria redirecionar. E obviamente uma página não pode impedir ninguém de fechar o browser.

Comment: rs rs... pensei que com jquery ou ajax nada fosse impossível... mas vamos lá... com jquery encontrei esse código: $(window).unload(function(){
    alert("Goodbye!");
});
Encontrei também esse código:
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
Porém preciso apenas desligar o usuário do sistema, colocar uma url('sair.php') por exemplo, apenas ler esse arquivo e continuar a execução do fechamento da página...

Answer (score 3):

O ideal seria não redirecioná-los, mas fazer uma requisição via ajax para esta página e de lá atualizar o status.

Para interceptar quando o browser está fechando e fazer uma requisição AJAX, pode-se usar o seguinte código:

```
window.onunload = function(ev) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '/caminho/para/update/do/status.php', true);
  request.send();
  request.onreadystatechanged = function(e) {
     if(this.status === 200 || this.statusText === 'OK') {
       // deu tudo certo
     } else {
       // muito provável que algo tenha dado errado
     }
  }
}
```

Embora não seja 100% necessário, jQuery também poderia ser usado no lugar de VanillaJS.

Comment: Olá thepanuto...no body coloco alguma coisa ou apenas esse código?

Comment: não é necessário... na página que está sendo fechada, somente uma tag script com esse código dentro. Na sua página `caminho/para/update/do/status.php` tem que haver um código PHP pra atualizar o status, de online pra offline.

Comment: Quase..rrsrsr... consigo agora mudar o status, porém o que está ocorrendo é que se eu sair pelo browser, outras pessoas acabam perdendo a sessão também... alterei linha request.open('POST', 'sair.php', true);  ...

Comment: Teria algum meio disso não acontecer?

Comment: Tenha certeza que não está alterando o status de mais ninguém ao fazer o update na página `sair.php`.

Comment: No sair.php eu pego a sessão de cada usuário, do qual acredito que rode somente no browser dele, mas mesmo assim desloga os outros. Depois tentei passar por querystring a variável de cada usuário para forçar o desligamento individual: sair.php?Key=$idUsuarios; ... mas também não funcionou...

Comment: Usando $_SESSION, você tem acesso somente à sessão do usuário que está atualmente visualizando a página. Para passar dados para a página, mande uma query string no `.send` do objeto, e.g. `request.send('keys=1,2,3');`

Comment: Olá thepanuto. Perdoe-me a ignorância mais uma vez. Nesse caso eu teria que pegar dess forma? "request.send(<?php echo $_SESSION['IdUsuarios']; ?>)"... o e.g coloco antes do request.send?

Comment: sim, mas no caso teria que ser uma query string, ou seja, no formato `'key1=foo&key2=bar'`. Antes do `.send`, vem todo o código da minha resposta, mas em vez do `.send()` vazio, você passa o resultado do php, e.g. `.send('<?php echo $minhaVar ?>')` e antes, atualize a variável `$minhaVar`.

Comment: Certo... só não consegui entender o e.g.. rs rs ... ficaria dessa forma? e.g.request.send(...)?

Comment: e.g. é latim para "exempli gratia", que significa "por exemplo", somente. O código da requisição é como está na resposta, mudando somente o `request.send`, que fica assim: `request.send('<?php echo $parametros ?>')`

Comment: certo thepanuto... foi testar aqui... obrigado pela ajuda...